# Syserr macro variable incorrectly zero?

Tags: sas

I have the following code:

```
data want;
set &dsetlist.;
run;
%put SYSERROR: &syserr.;
```

The macro variable dsetlist is a list of dataset views which, among other things, specify the length of certain variables to prevent truncation when the views are stacked together.

If I specify this length incorrectly, I will get a warning: multiple lengths were specified...

I would expect to see the following in my log:

```
data want;
set have1 have2 ... haven;
run;
WARNING: multiple lengths were specified...
NOTE: view have1 used
NOTE: view have2 used
...
NOTE: view haven used
SYSERROR: 4
```

However, unfortunately, SYSERROR is instead 0, despite the warnings.

My only thought is that perhaps syserror is being overwritten by each used view, and syserror = 0 as the last view ran without errors or warnings? If that is the case, how could I go about fixing this?

--

Edit: reproducible

```
data have1;
stacked = "Y";
run;
data have2;
stacked = "NO";
run;

data view1/view=view1;
length stacked $1.;
set have1;
run;
data view2/view=view2;
length stacked $1.;
set have2;
run;

data want;
set view1 view2;
run;
%put SYSERROR: &syserr.;
```

Apologies if I have made any errors in transcription, cannot c/p here.

If I am to change the last dataset to

```
data want;
length stacked $1.;
set have1 have2;
run;
%put SYSERROR: &syserr.;
```

that would indeed give me what I expect, but as the actual datastep views are accomplishing more than changing length, this is not ideal. Also, it's not entirely surprising that the data want segment does not return an error; the truncation instead is happening within the view...but that doesn't seem to be catchable by checking syserr after the view declaration, probably because it is not yet executed at that point.

Comment: I've tried to replicate this, and can't.  Can you create a test case that causes the value of 0?  My simple test cases (3 views, 2 of them have one length one another, trying both (A&B are 5) (C is 6) and (A is 5 B&C are 6) and (A&C are 5, B is 6), all cause `&syserr=4`.

Comment: Like @Joe I cannot replicate.  What version of SAS?

Comment: Test case created, running on SAS 9.2

Comment: Ahh, okay.  The warning occurs _behind_ the view.  That's probably the problem - &SYSERR for the execution of the view is 4, but for the execution of this data step is not 4.

Comment: Nate, are you able to use &SYSWARNINGTEXT?

Comment: Interestingly enough, yes, I am. Huh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the `VARLENCHK` option in the [SAS Docs](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a003269301.htm).  Try setting it to `option varlenchk=error` - that might trigger `SYSERR` to flag as you want it to.

Comment: Very useful, hadn't heard or thought to handle things that way. It does indeed cause syserror > 0 (1008 in this specific instance). However, reclassifying this warning as an error causes the data step in question to stop executing, which isn't how I would prefer to handle this scenario. Do you have any idea why the varlenchk=warn default wouldn't cause here a syserror of 4? (Execution completed, but with warnings)

Comment: If you need the datastep to complete, add code to catch SYSERR value and set it to 0 (this is not uncommon).  Alternatively, use a `length` statement before your `set` statement for the variable in question and set it to the largest value - that way, you avoid all the length statements for each dataset.  Another option is Proc SQL which, I think, takes the length of a variable from the first table queried.  Make sure the dset with longest is first and you should be OK.

Comment: You're right @Joe - the doc for syserr says it should be 4; I've removed that bit from my comment.  If I remember rightly, syserr is not very reliable when it comes to macros (though that shouldn't apply here as you're only using a macro variable).